# How to considered only modified files into github actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a set of folders like below:-

```
Example
    Folder A
        Folder B
           Folder C
              Y.yaml
              Z.md
    Folder D
        Folder E
           Folder F
              N.yaml
              O.md
    Folder G
        Folder H
           Folder I
              2.yaml
              3.md
```

with above folder structure, I have created the github action workflow as below. I'm able to get the diff files with this.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
    paths:
    - Example/** 

jobs:
  updatepages:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux]

    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./automation/
        
    permissions:
      contents: read
      id-token: write
      pull-requests: write
    
   steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        fetch-depth: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && 2 || 0 }}
        
    - name: Get changes
      id: changed-files
      run: |
        if ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}; then
          echo "changed_files=$(git diff --name-only -r HEAD^1 HEAD | xargs)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        else
          echo "changed_files=$(git diff --name-only ${{ github.event.before }} ${{ github.event.after }} | xargs)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        fi
     
    - name: Setup Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: 3.x

    - name: dependencies
      run: |
        pip install requests flask md2cf mistune

    - name: Run autodocu update
      run: |
        for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.changed_files }}; do
           python important.py
        done
```

**However, now I want to Achieve, if any file ending with .md extension has changed (added, modified, deleted) under any folder want to consider those files only, remaining it should ignore**

Comment: Is `paths` filter `'**/*.md'` not enough for your use case? See the [filter pattern cheat sheet](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet) for more details and examples.

Comment: maybe `git diff --name-only -r HEAD^1 HEAD | grep ".md" | xargs)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`